# Как не читать свойство объект до его получения

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть react-компонент:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHttp } from '../../hooks/http.hooks';

function Main() {
    const { loading, error, request } = useHttp(); // Для запросов
    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

    useEffect(async() => {
        takeNews(4)
    }, []);

    async function takeNews(quantity = 5) {
        const data = await request(`http://localhost:5500/api/news/top/${quantity}`); // Получаю массив из 4 объектов
        if (Array.isArray(data.news)) {
            setNews(data.news);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {news[0].content.headline}
        </>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

При первом рендере `news[0].content.headline` выдаст ошибку:

> Нельзя прочитать свойство из `undefined`.

Как можно игнорировать избежать этого? Единственное решение, которое я придумал, это расфасовать `news` на дочерние объекты, а потом сделать с ними тоже самое, но тогда в коде будет очень много неоправданных переменных и он будет некрасивым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно это сделать несколькими способами (при условии что в вашем кастомном эта переменная изменяется):

```
if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
return (
    <>
       {news[0].content.headline}
    </>
);
```

Можно воспользоваться например функцией [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) из `lodash`

```
return (
        <>
            {get(news, "[0].content.headline", "No Data")}
            
        </>
    );
```

Можно проверить длину массива:

```
if (news.length === 0) return "No Data";
return (
        <>
            {news[0].content.headline}
            
        </>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно также использовать [опциональный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
const obj = {}

console.log(obj?.a?.b) // undefined
console.log(obj.a.b) // error
```

Пока оператор не сильно хорошо поддерживается и в некоторых браузерах может возникнуть SyntaxError, поэтому можно использовать сравнение через `&&`:

```js
const obj = {}

console.log(obj.a && obj.a.b) // undefined
```